# C++: Force separate instances of a class for code protection

Tags: c++, obfuscation

This may sound strange, but for purposes of obfuscation, I'm wondering if there's a way to create multiple instances of a class throughout my app, but instead of them all reusing the same underlying code, the compiler would create completely separate chunks of code for that class. Sort of an inline for a class.

This would need to work in Xcode and Visual Studio.

The reason for this, and in all fairness, this is an idea that I'm just playing with...I'm looking for another level to slow down a hacker from patching my license code. Typically, no matter how hard you try to prevent code hacking, there ends up being one place where your code returns something like a true/false....Is this license valid? And if a hacker finds that one spot, it's a simple patch. My idea is to try putting the license code, specially the same license class, all throughout my app...many of them...and check any one of them at any time. And if it's done well, the hacker might have to find 10 of them...not knowing that there's really something like 20 of them throughout my app. And all this would depend on writing one class, but it can't be the same piece of reused class code...they'd need to be all separate.

Any ideas?

Comment: make it a template

Comment: Also, why do you think this helps with obfuscation?

Comment: Also, why do you think you need to obfuscate?

Comment: maybe define macro's with the name of your class

Comment: My reasoning is that rather than a hacker finding the one piece of code that determines if a license is legal, he'd have to find 10 or more of them instead. Why the down votes? It's an odd, but completely reasonable question.

Comment: @pizzafilms: Does your code check all instances in sequence? If not, then the hacker probably only needs to access the one that's used at the key point. Which makes it a single check, trivial to track down every instance.

Comment: The idea would be to check any of them at any time. The hacker could think he's patched it, but at some point later it would fail.

Comment: You need to clear up requirements. You want a different type for each instance? As it is required it's hard to guess precisely. What exactly do you want to have duplicated, code for methods? Should then every method work on every instance of the obfuscated class? It's going to be hard to duplicate the code while making it compatible on binary level. Otherwise you can make up different type for each instance.

Comment: My idea...albeit, just an idea...was that I'd write my License class once, but instead of just having it in one place, where a hacker could patch, there would be many of them sprinkled throughout my app, all triggered at different times, so hopefully it would be harder to patch.

Comment: Ok, I guess a template with some parameter as randomizer would suit the purpose. You could randomize both data layout and methods with it. And in the code you could instantiate it with `Licence<1337>` or `Licence<42>`. If they don't have to be interoperable then it's fine.

Comment: Thanks @luk32. If that were an answer I'd check it.

Comment: When asking this kind of questions I'd suggest you to mention in your posts *why* you try to do that. Otherwise many people will just downvote because the question may seem meaningless and move on without reading the comments.

Comment: +1 I'd advise to try clear up the title. Because "separate instance of a class" does not have much meaning.

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't know how else to word it.

Comment: *"Sort of inline for a class"* Do you mean just inlining class methods? Because if so, `__forceinline` (MSVC) and `__attribute__((always_inline))` (GCC/clang) applied to class methods could help.

Comment: No, I didn't mean inlining just a method, I meant an entire class. Sorry, I didn't know the best way to word this as I'm sure this doesn't come up very often. @luk32 's answer below (and gracious code example) is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt/proof of concept. I've drafted a class which has:

1. some garbage data based on a template argument, so it's harder to reuse data layout.
2. a method with side effect based on on a template argument, so it's harder to reuse the code

One should be aware that this is all tricky, because compiler is allowed to do any transformation on the code which preserves observable behaviour. Thus, just using a template with a param, would produce two distinct type language wise, but the code generated could be reused for both.

I am not sure whether an experienced hacker would draw any conclusions about the code, or even whether the license check code itself would be duplicated. It's possible. Below code shows that `method` has two occurences in which one is a loop and the other got unwound, see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/kWvXTQ) assembly lines 108-113 and 134-142.

That being said, often optimization is a nice obfuscator. Maybe on times even better than hand-mangling.

This a way to start. Generally `constexpr` and templates are our friends in such cases, because they are processed at compile time, we need to ensure the generate unique things. One could probably try some `constexpr` hashing, etc.

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

template<int N>
struct B {
    constexpr B() : arr() {
        for (auto i = 0; i != N; ++i)
            arr[i] = i; 
    }
    int arr[N];
};

template<int Randomizer = 42>
struct  A{
    string a{"data_a"}; // probably all member should be templated by Randomizer
    B<Randomizer> padding;
    string b{"data_b"};

    void method() {
        cout << a << "\n";
        for(int i = 0; i<Randomizer; i++) {
            cout << padding.arr[i]; // harmless side effect
        }
        cout << "\n" << b << "\n";
    }
};

int main () {
    A<> i1;
    A<3> i2;

    i1.method();
    i2.method();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Xcode is saying "Statement not allowed in constexpr constructor" on the for loop in B...

Comment: It looks like that for loop is only allowed in C++14 and I'm using C++11. Any idea how to modify that for C++11?